# partitioning the integers without arithmetic progressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the least $n$ such that the set of all integers can be partitioned into $n$ disjoint subsets, none of which contain any infinite arithmetic progressions (arbitrarily long but finite arithmetic progressions are allowed)? In particular, can it be done for $n=2$? I tried e.g. splitting the integers into perfect powers and non-powers but then $4n+2$ is never a perfect power.

Comment: How about creating 2 subsets A and B as follows: put 1 into A, then 2,3 into B, then 4,5,6,7 into A etc. Where the number going into each set doubles at each step. Could A or B contain an infinite arithmetic progression?

Comment: Are you disallowing uni-directional arithmetic series, or just bi-directional arithmetic series?

Comment: Disallowing uni-directional arithmetic series. Why did I miss something as simple as $...-5,-4,1,4,5,6,7...$?

Comment: If you are only forbidding bi-directional arithmetic series, then you can just choose $A_1=\{0,2,4,...,-1,-3,-5,...\}$ and $A_2=\{-2,-4,-6,...,1,3,5,...\}$

Comment: @Thomas: It's useful to use a semicolon (;) or a pipe (|) as a separator, to indicate that "$\ldots$" isn't supposed to "connect" to the numbers on one side. e.g. {0,2,4,...|-1,-3,-5,...}

Answer (score -1):

I believe something like $X_i=[-10^i,-10^{i-1})$ and $Y_i=[10^{i-1},10^i)$, and then take $$A\;=\;\dots,X_7,X_5,X_3,X_1,0,Y_1,Y_3,Y_5,\dots$$ and $$B\;=\;\dots, X_6,X_4,X_2,-1,Y_2,Y_4,Y_6,\dots$$ to be the 2 parts partitioning the integers. As the gaps in either part increase in both directions, any arithmetic progression with common difference $d$ must be finite. This is because as you go far enough along $A$ (or $B$) in either direction, you will find a gap of length greater than $2d$.